# Fatal error - Class 'context_condition_node' in date_context module

Tags: wsod

I'm debugging a site that has completely broken - not finding too much out there and hoping for some help. The error I see is:

Fatal error: Class 'context_condition_node' not found /sites/all/modules/contrib/date/date_context/date_context.module on line 56

Anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means this module is missing or registry is broken.

Can you check if the date module does exist?

If not you may try to download a copy of date module and put it in the exactly the folder.

Use Drush `drush cc all` to clear the cache.

In Drupal 7 you can also go to admin performance page to clear the cache. Sometimes this is still available by admin/config/development/performance.

If it still does not work, you may want to have a go with [registry_rebuild](https://drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild) module to rebuild the registry totally.

Comment: Yup it was a registry issue. I had to actually remove date module and re-add it for some reason, but now it's resolved. Thanks!